# Vector (scalar) product: associativity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$. Consider this scalar result:
$b = x^{\top} y z$.

The issue is that the above product does not follow the classical associativity algerbra rules, i.e. we can not set
$b = x^{\top} (y z)$.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: Your example has to do with associativity, not with commutativity. Yes, there are non-associative algebraic structures such as Lie algebras and Jordan algebras. There is nothing wrong with non-associativity. Maybe you would like to clarify your question.

Comment: A question on notation: how do you define the product $yz$? Is it the cross product of vectors? If yes, it does not exist for all $n$. Let us suppose that the result $yz$ is a vector, however: is $x^T(yz)$ just the scalar product $\langle x, yz\rangle$?

Comment: btw Welcome to Math Stack Exchange :)

Comment: $x x^{\top} y$ = $x (x^{\top} y)$  = $(x^{\top} y) x$ !=  $x^{\top} (y x)$. The ability of using the commutativity property seems confusing. No?

Comment: Even before considering commutativity you should define the operations: what do you mean with $yx$, $x^Tx$? Which operations are you considering?

Comment: superscript T denotes the transpose, while $x^{\top} y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i$.

Comment: I had this exact question, it seems so simple, how is there not an answer?